# How To Remove "Messaging And Reporting " from Openerp Menu?

Tags: openerp-7

[image]
I had install Accounting and Finance, but there are two more options as Messaging and Reporting which I don't want in Menu. Is there any way to remove it from Menu ?

Answer (score 1):

Override this menu item and assign group (create new group) which has no access to any user then it will hide from all users.

```
<menuitem name="Messaging" id="mail.mail_feeds_main" groups="base.group_user" sequence="10"/>
```

The same thing for reporting menu item.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. Viraj, But my Issue is not this one, Now I added a Screen you may find the solution.

Comment: Yes I got your question, 

you just need to create another module and set your xml code to hide menu   and install module then see, you will not see menu,

You have one more option for that,
Create group from GUI and do not assign this group to any user.
Then go to settings -> User Interface -> Menu Items 
search menus and remove all groups from this menu and set your newly created group there and check.